# Slicer in PowerBI Desktop has different format in PowerBI Server, display bug

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals, power-bi-report-server

I've got an issue with the slicer format.

Other users see the slicer correctly (as it is set in PBI Desktop), while I see a totally different format on the PBI Server. I'm not sure if I'm the only one experiencing this issue.

PBI Desktop:

[correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Umfk.png)

PBI Server, same slicer different tabs:

[incorrect 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsFOY.png)
[incorrect 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ5Ab.png)

I'm using the newest Edge, I've cleaned cookies. I've experienced this issue in another dashboard as well. What else can I do? And how to make sure that other users have a proper display of the filter?